# Why should I use final keyword on @Autowired method of Abstract Classes?

Tags: spring

I was reading [Using @Autowired in Abstract Classes](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowired-abstract-class). In here, I could not understand this "When we use @Autowired on a setter method, we should use the final keyword, so that the subclass can't override the setter method. Otherwise, the annotation won't work as we expect.". (tried to find some example but couldn't find one)

Could you give me an example of an unexpectedly working scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal example to show the problem:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication extends AutowiredBase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String get() {
        return timeProvider.getTime();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTimeProvider(final TimeProvider timeProvider) {
        // never called, because this method is not autowired
        super.setTimeProvider(timeProvider);
    }

}

@Component
class TimeProvider {
    public String getTime() {
        return Instant.now().toString();
    }
}

class AutowiredBase {
    protected TimeProvider timeProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void setTimeProvider(final TimeProvider timeProvider) {
        System.out.println("Autowiring time provider");
        this.timeProvider = timeProvider;
    }
}
```

`DemoApplication#setTimeProvider` will never be called, therefore calling the `get()` method will result in an NPE. If you comment the overridden method and leave the base method, everything works as expected.

Comment: The example is so nice to understand, I appreciate it.